# Prestashop: how to override a module class contained in a file that includes other classes?

Tags: php, module, overriding, prestashop-1.6

prestashop overriding system works like many others by using the file naming scheme. So basically, I'll create a class in /overrides/classes with the same class and file name of another in /classes, just to simplify. Well, I've got to override this (with latest prestashop versions a module can be overridden, with previous we couldn't):

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/MailAlert.php');

class MailAlerts extends Module{

[....]

}
```

I can override it with this:

```
class MailAlertsOverride extends MailAlerts{

[....]

}
```

Well, it works, the file and the class get recognized, but I've got problems with the originally included MailAlert class. I cannot reinclude it, but if I don't include it, the module will ask for it.

I'd prefer not to modify the parent class. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I was wrong: the code above just works :)

For those who didn't know (it's a relatively new prestashop feature), you can override a module in `/override/modules/[modulename]/[modulename.php]`

And using the special class naming you can read above: `modulenameOverride extends modulename`

Comment: Thank you.. I tried it, and I stucked with class naming. After I renamed my custom class name to modulenameOverride, everything works great